# python logging does not work from terminal

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to use the logging module in Python.
This is my simple script

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename = 'logging.log', format = '%(message)s', filemode = 'a', level = logging.DEBUG)
logging.info('some info')
```

It works when I run the script from a Python editor (I use Spyder), but it doesn't work if I try to run the script from terminal with:

```
python ~/PYTHON/untitled0.py
```

untitled0.py is the name of the script in my PYTHON folder.
Am I doing something wrong?

I use Python 2.7.2+ with Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Where have you checked for your `logging.log` file?  `~/PYTHON`?  Or somewhere else?

Comment: To clarify: your log file should be on the current directory, not in ~/PYTHON.

Comment: yes, I was checking in the wrong folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake i see here is you have to check the directory path where you are executing this script as the logging.log is created there.

Ex: `$ python ~/PYTHON/untitled0.py`

```
$ cat logging.log
```

and not

```
cat ~/PYTHON/logging.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common mistake when people work up a script and then start invoking it in some "different way" (e.g. shortcut icon, scheduler, shell script etc).

If you are unclear about what is going on with your script try cutting and pasting this to the top of your script or replacing your (backed up) script with this source:

```
import sys
import os

print "argv: %r"%(sys.argv,)
print "dirname(argv[0]): %s"%os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))
print "pwd: %s"%os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(os.path.curdir))
```